# Trying to programmatically create new Windows user's profile

Tags: active-directory, users

Trying the low-impact solution as mentioned in the post:

[how can I programmatically cause a new windows users profile to be created](https://serverfault.com/questions/946882/how-can-i-programmatically-cause-a-new-windows-users-profile-to-be-created)

Suggestion was to run a command as that user using psexec.exe for Windows to create the profile:

```
psexec.exe -u <domain/user name for AD user> -p <password> cmd.exe /c exit
```

I'm running it local to the VM I've created.  Getting the message :

```
PsExec could not start cmd.exe:
The user name or password is incorrect
```

Can someone give me insight into what I'm doing wrong?  My purpose is to create the user folder in the C:\Users area based upon the AD user I set up, without them or me having to log in to toggle this user folder creation.

Comment: Hi @Pflipper could you use net user /add?  I'm not sure about AD way of doing it but I often do `net user /add "USER" "PASSWD" /fullname "Hairy Mclairy"`

Comment: Hi Mr R.  I tried this option, even mentioned in the referred post, this does not cause the profile itself to be created.  It does create the AD user, but I would like the actual user folder (C:\Users\<user name>) to be created without having to log in myself under this user, or have the user log on in order to create this.

Comment: Hmm - wierd - we do `net user /add` then change password expiry using `wmic useraccount` then do `net localgroup SPECIFICGROUP USER /add` .. I wouldn't have thought either of the last two would cause the user folder to be created ...  Are you running on the box (we do via SSH and an appropriately privaleged user)? or remotely?

Comment: I am running this directly on the server.

Comment: And the user gets created? if you do `net user SPECIFICUSER` do you get a dump showing anything?

Comment: Yes, it shows a number of properties for the user.  But again, I'm trying to create the user folder in the C:\Users area based upon the AD user I set up, without them or me having to log in to toggle this user folder creation.   From what I see, net user /add does not do this.

Comment: This suggests it happens on first login - https://serverfault.com/questions/836797/windows-create-domain-users-home-directory-before-login

Comment: Yes, it does.  And the prior post referenced in my original question says that you can toggle it to occur prior to login by using the "psexec.exe ..." command referenced above.  That's not working for me, and what I'm requesting help with.

Comment: You did the net user /add first? then the psexec?

Comment: And the user running is I'm guessing needing to be an administrator?

Comment: I am admin on this VM.  And the user is added first.  then psexec

Comment: Can you post EXACTLY what you typed - can remove the password but leave everything else EXACTLY as typed..

Comment: C:\Users\COC\Downloads\PSTools\psexec.exe -u COCUsers\COCP1 -p 123$abc cmd.exe /c exit....  password included

Comment: Perhaps @Pflipper you need to use the _local username_ in this case?  (i.e. drop COCUsers\?)..

Comment: Good morning Mr. R.  COCP1 is a local user name.

Comment: I meant `-u COCP1` not `-u COCUsers\COCP1`?

Comment: Yep, used them both.  -u <domain>\<user> and -u <user>. Same outcome.

Comment: What about quotes around the password?

Comment: Tried as well.  Are you familiar with psexec.exe?

Comment: sorry only what I've read here - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec - and the linked article underneath it.  It was written along time ago - I wonder whether it's now locked out because it was a vector for trojans ...

Comment: OK, well thanks anyway.  Seems you've thought of the same things I've thought of.  Perhaps someone will weigh in with other suggestions based upon the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at this ansible module - win_user_profile.  The powershell script (which is the ansible module) can be found here: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.windows/blob/3afe02165344bf46534a9b56766e68531addac43/plugins/modules/win_user_profile.ps1

Of interest to you would be lines 35-58 (where the Ansible.WinUserProfile.NativeMethods class is created) and 130 to 146ish.  You could base your own process off of this, or at the very least it would point you in one direction to achieve what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old of a thread but I came upon it while looking for a way to create a user's profile folder structure properly during a new image build script for specific customization that were not possible by GPO etc.

If you run a remote powershell Invoke-Command with the user's credentials, it will build the user profile folder under C:\Users if it doesn't already exist and you can then manipulate it and also the HKCU registry keys as needed.

This command does nothing but the exit command, but will create the user's profile if it doesn't already exist:

***Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerVar -ScriptBlock {exit} -Credential $credentialVar***

Obviously the user's creds have to have the rights to connect remotely, and the OS firewall can't be blocking said connections but otherwise, this command will do what you are looking for at least.